# Unable to resolve module `./index` from ``:

Tags: react-native

The command 'react-native run-android' is success, but the terminal 'react-native start' report the error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from ``:

None of these files exist:
  * index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * index\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\web\taobao\umiRNExample-master\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\web\taobao\umiRNExample-master\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\web\taobao\umiRNExample-master\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at D:\web\taobao\umiRNExample-master\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\web\taobao\umiRNExample-master\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:841:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\web\taobao\umiRNExample-master\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (D:\web\taobao\umiRNExample-master\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: Make sure index.js exist and if it doesn't try creating one or create new react native project from scratch

Comment: Ok, It works. The index.js is lost indeed. I use umi framework, and I execute 'yarn watch'  so the temporate file index.js created, then 'start' and 'run' works. Thank you so much.